# Bmesh: Immediately encounter strange error after adding new layer and running bmesh op

Tags: python, bmesh

The script is simple:

```
import bpy, bmesh

mesh = bpy.context.edit_object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)
geom = [e for e in bm.verts[:] + bm.edges[:] + bm.faces[:] if e.select]

cut_layer = bm.edges.layers.int.new('cut')
ret = bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(bm, geom=geom , plane_co=(0,1,0), plane_no=(0, 1, 0))
bm.edges.layers.int.remove(cut_layer)

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh)
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: geom: 8 BMEdge has been removed
```

Here's an example blend file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9DFPZBPKp6ARjE5NXgzSTU0eDQ

Can anyone explain what's going wrong here?
I know the function itself looks a little pointless but that's because I've boiled the problem down to it's simplest form.
Why does the operation have a problem with the new edge layer I've added?
I can't find anything online about this...

Answer (score 1):

Assign your int layer before you assign geometry.  PS took out verts from bisectable geometry.

```
import bpy, bmesh

mesh = bpy.context.edit_object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)
cut_layer = bm.edges.layers.int.new('cut')
geom = [e for e in bm.edges[:] + bm.faces[:] if e.select]

ret = bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(bm, geom=geom , plane_co=(0,1,0), plane_no=(1, 0, 0))
bm.edges.layers.int.remove(cut_layer)

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh)
```

Comment: This is a bit of a problem as I'm creating my own bmesh operations as it were, which make no reference to selected elements, but receive parameters as lists of geometry (just like the built-in bmesh ops).
Is there some way I can keep the order of my original code while fixing the problem? Even if it means iterating over all the input geom after adding the new layer.

Comment: Thank you batFINGER, Wouldn't have guessed from the error msg (TypeError: geom: 0 BMVert has been removed) that it had something to do with a custom data layer.